# Comparing String arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, text, split

I have two String arrays one from a text file other one is from user. I split them with split method. And I want to compare them one by one. In other words compare Userword[0] with split[0], split[1], split[2]... , Userword[1] with split[0], split[1], split[2]... In text file every word has its own values to multiply. Here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class Ai2 {

    private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static List<Ai2> list = new ArrayList<Ai2>();
    private static String[] split;
    private static String[] Userword;

    private static double number1;
    private static double number2;
    private static double number3;
    private static double multPos = 0;
    private static double multNeg = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        String sentence = null;
        System.out.println("\nEnter a sentence please");
        sentence = scan.nextLine();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Alparslan\\Desktop\\words.txt"));
            String txt = " ";
            String msg = " ";
            while((msg = br.readLine()) != null){
                txt += msg;
            }//words in the text is taken to txt variable in this area.

            for(int i=0; i<sentence.length(); i++){
                split = txt.split(" ");
                // Sentence boşluğa göre ayrılıyor ve split adındaki diziye
                // başarıyla aktarılıyor. kontrol için alttaki yazlılabilir.
                //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
            }
            for(int i=0; i<sentence.length(); i++){
                 Userword = sentence.split(" ");
                // Sentence boşluğa göre ayrılıyor ve split adındaki diziye
                // başarıyla aktarılıyor. kontrol için alttaki yazlılabilir.
                //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Userword));
            }
            for (int i =0; i<sentence.length(); i++) {
                for(int j=0; j<sentence.length(); i++){

                    if(Userword[i].equals(split[j])){
                    multPos *= 0.6*Double.parseDouble(split[i+1]);
                    multNeg *= 0.4*Double.parseDouble(split[i+2]);
                }
                }//internal for
            }//external for

            if(multPos>multNeg){
                System.out.println("The Sentence is positive" + multPos);
            }else{
                System.out.println("The Sentence is negative" + multNeg);
            }

            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Ai2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
      } 
}
```

Edit: I deleted String[] s so I do not create new arrays sorry for this. I write in this way but I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 error

Comment: What's not working? What's the error you're getting? What have you tried?

Comment: you are creating new arrays instead of giving values to the ones you want

Comment: Why are you so nervous. everybody can do sometimes wrong things. I write my code I write what I wanted. If I write them here, you should know 'professionals' this code is not working. If you really are professionals you know where exactly is not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
    for(int i=0; i<Userwords.length;i++){
          for(j=0; j<split.length;j++){
               if(Userwords[i].equals(split[j]){
                     //THEY COMPARE TO EACH OTHER RETURN SOMETHING
               }

          }

        }
```

Its a pseudo code example

EDITED:
You can make something like this than:

```
           for(int i=0; i<Userwords.length;i++){
              for(j=0; j<split.length;j++){
                 try{  
                   if(Userwords[i].equals(split[j]){
                         //THEY COMPARE TO EACH OTHER RETURN SOMETHING
                   }
                }catch(Exception ex){}
              }

            }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I tried already this. I am getting nullpoint exception when I tried in this way. but used arrays are full. in for loops when I write System.out.println s I can see full arrays.

Comment: than add there a try catch statement, maybe not every box of the array is filled!

Comment: @AlparslanDevelioğlu i add some edited code to my answer

Comment: @AlparslanDevelioğlu than please vote my comments up and my answer ;) Thank you for your support